16 year old boy looking for recommendations for a Lightweight, Durable Bicycle for Daily Commute (18 km) with Back Pedal and Single Gear
For a 16-year-old looking to commute 18 km daily, a single-speed, back-pedal (coaster brake) bike that’s lightweight, durable, and within a 600-euro budget is absolutely achievable. this was your last answer Title: Recommendations for a Lightweight, Durable Bicycle for Daily Commute (18 km) with Back Pedal and Single Gear
Body:
I’m looking for advice on selecting a bicycle for my 16.5-year-old son, who needs a reliable bike for his daily commute of 18 kilometers. We prioritize comfort and durability, and we’d like a bike that features a back pedal brake and a single gear for simplicity.
Summary of the Problem:
My son will be using this bike primarily for commuting, so it needs to be lightweight for easy handling and transport. We're also looking for a model that requires minimal maintenance, as we want to avoid frequent repairs or complicated upkeep.
Details:
Distance: 18 km round trip daily
Features Desired:
Back pedal brake
Single gear
Lightweight frame
Durable and comfortable for daily use
Maintenance: Low maintenance is a key requirement.
Budget - till 600 euors
Research:
I have looked into various models available in the Dutch market and found options from brands like Gazelle and Cortina, but I'm unsure which specific models might meet our criteria. I also read about the benefits of single-gear bikes for commuting but would appreciate further insights.
What I've Tried:
I’ve visited a couple of local bike shops and tested a few models, but I would like more specific recommendations based on other users' experiences or expert advice on what features to look for.
Any recommendations or insights on suitable models would be greatly appreciated!  also please suggest the best shop to buy in Amsterdam or to wait for black friday

One bit of information that would be helpful is the expected terrain that will be on the commute.  Is it flat, or are there climbs and descents to navigate?

If Amsterdam is the area, no real hills but strong winds are a given.

@TedHohl Amsterdam must be top of league table for flattest city, no?

This question is 75% ChatGPT copy-pasta

Did you take the rider shopping with you?   What you want may not match what he wants.

The most hilly bits in Amsterdam are the bridges and of those there are many. But most of those do not require gears. Only if you have to cross the big shipping canals having gears can be important. The problem with single gear and back pedal brake bikes is that they are mostly either light or good.

@Noise, I was thinking that myself, but the question should be a little more durable (informative) regardless.  And Willeke's comment regarding the winds comes into play as well.

Suggestion: aim for "features" not models   This will increase relevance over time and location, where your models are not available elsewhere or in the future

Don't wait for black friday, the price reductions then will mostly be inflated prices being brought down to normal in the Netherlands. The few real deals are often out of fashion or last seasons models, which will be well priced now as well.
At 16 your son should be ready for a better bike than a simple single speed back pedal break. There will be some of those in the shops in the Netherlands but most of those will not be light and reliable.
If it gives a better range of bikes in the shop a 5 or 7 speed internal hub gears 'naafversnelling' and drum or roller brakes is as easy to maintain and will give a better ride.
A derailleur bike will likely much lighter and at 18 km that will make a difference.
You tagged this question Amsterdam and mention wanting to shop in that city, so I assume the commute will be in that area, if so, hills will not be a consideration. Wind will be, so a lighter bike with a better aero position might work for him.
We do not recommend brands nor shops here, but if you go to a bike shop with a good reputation every bike they recommend should be reliable and backed by their services.
If you want to go for a simple bike to keep the expenses within limits, consider a second hand bike of a more expensive brand. On the other hand, if you want a single gear back pedal brake to discourage thieves consider a Swap fiets (rental with the blue tire) which are insured against theft.
